# What does "きゅうにゅう" means?

Tags: word-choice, dictionary

I was trying to memorize some Japanese words using Memrise app (Duolingo's new memorizing app). I came up with this word which means "milk/cow milk" according to memrise. But I couldn't find any translations for this one on any Japanese dictionaries. Is this a real word or memrise just made it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be **ぎ**ゅうにゅう meaning "milk", although ミルク is much more common.

Comment: Yes, ぎゅうにゅう is milk, but I don't agree that ミルク is much more common.  Perhaps does that depend on generation?

Comment: @Ryo:  It may be regional too.  I never heard 牛乳 in Osaka.  In fact, I may have only heard it in textbooks.

Comment: Might be a regional difference. During my travels in Japan, at my home-stay in 大阪, my host family and friends would reference it as ミルク more often than 牛乳. The opposite was true in 東京, where mostly younger people would sometimes use ミルク but most people would use 牛乳 most of the time.